# Selenium WebDriver how to select a random option from select option menu excluding one option

Tags: selenium, random, selenium-webdriver

I have code select option:

```
Select kraj = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("kraj")));
kraj.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size()));
```

This code is ok, but i'd like exclude one of the select option to be random.
How can I do this?

selectByIndex random all index, but I'd like the first index would not be random (first index named always the same: "--your choice--"

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Do you mean to say that you want to exclude the first index (default option) when trying to select a random option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
// Assume the select has 5 options
Random random = new Random();

// Get a random number between 0 and 3 (that is size - 1, random.nextInt() generated is 0 inclusive, 4 exclusive.
int optionIndex = random.nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size() - 1);

// Increment optionIndex by 1 to pick an option between 1 to 4
kraj.selectByIndex(optionIndex++);
```

The above code is essentially the opposite of `random.nextInt(range)` where 0 is exclusive and range-1 is inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

add couple of lines of code to define a range

```
Random randomOption = new Random();       
int startOption = 1; //assuming "--your choice--" is index "0"
int endOption = user_country.getOptions().size()); // end of range  

int number = startOption + randomOption .nextInt( endOption - startOption);
```

//then do your stuff

```
Select kraj = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("kraj")));
kraj.selectByIndex(number );
```

Comment: I don't understand this: `(endOption - startOption + 1)` It is not enough only `(endOption - startOption)`?

Comment: in this case you are right. You can use (endOption - startOption) only

Answer (score 0):

@ivan Try This

`Select menu = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
menu.selectByVisibleText("Enter the option which you want to select");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    int random=0;
    do{
    random=new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size());
    }while(random==0);

    Select kraj = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("kraj")));
    kraj.selectByIndex(random);
```

The above loop **will run till the value of random comes out not equal to '0'**. In case the value of random is different, then it will come out of the loop and select the related index of the selection menu.

You can change the the value in **while(random==0)** from "0" to any other value that comes in the range of **'0 to user_country.getOptions().size()-1'**  and that will be excluded from selection.